# I installed my them, where is it on my menu?

Tags: magento2

I installed fullpack theme, and i haven't got monster ico, where is it on my left menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following commands and check:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If it still does not help please clear your **generation** folder of Magento and check.

Comment: bin/magento cache:clean - works
bin/magento setup:upgrade - works
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy - works

but,  no content imported.  and monster ico doesn't work too.

"If it still does not help please clear your generation folder of Magento and check.?"

Comment: I upload newest/paid theme and works